# Pasting screenshot changes colors in Photoshop CS3

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, color-profile

I've done search after search, messed with color profiles, image color management, etc, but I still find that when I simply print screen and paste it in Adobe Photoshop CS3, I get a much lighter image. It even looks like it has less colors, or JPEG compression artefacts.

I've tried flipping between sRGB, Macintosh RGB modes etc. If I paste the screen capture in windows paint, it's absolutely fine. Any ideas?

Comment: can you show, screen shot how it looks like in PS.

Comment: I laughed when you said Windows Paint.

Comment: Notepad, MSPaint, the vanilla tools sometimes do the job ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled my monitors color profiles (it only had one), and now everything is working fine. The colors on both my monitors match and don't screw up when pasting screen captures.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using File > Open ... rather than paste? There can be some issues with the clipboard. It could also be your color proofing settings.